# Read on-chain data with foundry

Tags: foundry

I know the ethereum address of a deployed smart contract.
I know the source code of this contract but I am not the owner.

Is there a way, with foundry tools to read this smart contract's variables ?

I also want to know if it is possible to interact with this smart contrat from foundry tools command line (call a method, ...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cast call](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-call) command line utility to read on-chain data. It's part of the foundry suite.

```sh
cast call --help
```

You'll need to know the signature of the function you want to call.
Eg : To check the `totalSupply()` of a token :

```
cast call 0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F "totalSupply()(uint256)" --rpc-url https://polygon.llamarpc.com
```

To check `balanceOf(address)` :

```
cast call 0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F "balanceOf(address)(uint256)" 0x53AB61eE41FA202227Eb4e7B176208FC626DC8A9 --rpc-url https://polygon.llamarpc.com
```

Comment: What is 0x53AB61eE41FA202227Eb4e7B176208FC626DC8A9 ?

Comment: It's just a wallet address. I'm checking what is the Polygon USDT balance for that wallet.